# Select export picture from HTML with selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

I tried to export the generated chart to png file from the menu in this [website](https://re.jrc.ec.europa.eu/pvg_tools/en/). After I manage to enter a city name and Visualize Results with script, the website shows some information and chart where I can export to png, either with small or large option. However, I could not manage to export large png file (option that I selected) of the chart because the script reach the timeout exception. The following is line that I've tried:

```
elem = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'tr_exportpngl')))
elem.click()
```

i tried also solutions from other questions such as wait until 'lement_to_be_clickable' or finding by XPATH, still no success.

```
elem = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[@id="tr_exportpngl"]')))
elem.click()
```

How can i make this work?

i look forward for your suggestion. thank you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, before clicking this button you need to click the export button which opens the dropdown with the options. This code did the thing:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from time import sleep


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get('https://re.jrc.ec.europa.eu/pvg_tools/en/')
driver.find_element(By.ID, 'map').click()
sleep(2)
driver.find_element(By.ID, 'tr_visualize').click()
sleep(2)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@class="highcharts-button"]').click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'tr_exportpngl'))).click()
```

Comment: It works.. thanks for your hint and answer..

Answer (score 0):

To enable download csv button you need first to click on the map.
So, after opening the link you need to wait for map to become clickable, then click on it.
Add a short delay to allow the file to be generated and then click on download csv button.
The following code works clearly:

```py
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=webdriver_service)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

url = "https://re.jrc.ec.europa.eu/pvg_tools/en/"
driver.get(url)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".ol-viewport canvas"))).click()
time.sleep(0.5)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "horizondownloadcsv"))).click()
```